# React / React-Native : Can I trigger methods in two different components based on a trigger?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, supabase

For a chat application I am making, I have two screens - one displaying the contacts with a notification blimp to show new messages and one screen displaying the chat with a contact. I have my database on supabase, and they provide a subscription to see for database changes. Any time a user gets a new message, I need to display that message in the chats and a notification blimp in the contacts screen.
The chat screen is called from within the contact screen

Where do I place the subscription code so I can trigger functions to do both my actions?
This is the code to subscribe.

[Code to subscribe to DB changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wH3bA.png)

I tried keeping the subscription code in the chat screen and using a callback function passed as a prop to update the contact screen. However, the subscription only runs after I open the chat screen. Until I do that, I get no information.

Comment: One possible solution is to put the subscription code at the very beginning of your app (e.g. `App.tsx`). Inside the subscription, store `payload.new` in a [context](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useContext) as part of the app's global state. You can then let both your screens access `payload.new` from the context. Thus, once a new `payload.new` is seen, both your screens will get updated.

Comment: Have you tried using  **useEffect** in your 2 different child components . Sample working shown [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/refresh-on-message-d02o1v?file=/src/ContactsList.js)  .. Once you recieve result as new message, change the variable passed to components. This will trigger your useEffect and execute functionality , if this is what is required....

Comment: @FanchenBao Oh I didn't think about using a context to store the new data. If there is a change in the context state, It will cause a re-render in both my child components, yes but however I also need to trigger a method every time the context changes. Is it possible to listen to context state changes?

Comment: @HamzaMushtaq I think what you have might be the solution, I'm gonna try keeping a state for the new message in the parent component and pass it down so I can listen to changes in the child components. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @HamzaMushtaq's solution would work. I'd like to build on it with my earlier suggestion of context. Make the value in the context the optional second argument to `useEffect`. Then when the context changes upon receiving a new message, your function in `useEffect` on both screens will be triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining both @HamzaMushtaq and @FanchenBao 's comments, I was able to solve this. The idea was to lift the state up and handle the subscription in the App.js. As soon as there is a change, I set the context state to payload.new. I import this context and the hook useContext allows me to access it's values. With a useEffect, I listen to changes in the context and fire my methods based on it.